# The cdf of a beta variable, evaluated at the mean

Tags: probability, inequality, special-functions

Consider a Beta random variable $X$ with shape parameters $k/2$ and $(d-k)/2$, where the parameters $k, d$ are integers that satisfy $0 < k < d$.  What is the best possible upper bound for the following probability?
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ X < \mathbb{E}(X) \}
$$
So far, after several days of toil, the best result I have been able to prove is a wretched 0.922.  This is based on a nontrivial normal approximation proposed by Alfers & Dinges (1984) and refined by Artstein (2002).

Numerical examples suggest that the extremal case occurs when $k = 1$ for every $d \geq 1$.  Furthermore, for this case, the limiting value as $d \to \infty$ appears to be equal to $\Phi(1) - \Phi(-1)$, where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

I can obtain considerably better bounds for this special case, but I have no idea how to prove that these parameters are extremal.  Any thoughts?